# Unable to receive messages and incoming events using Quckblox and Flutter

Tags: flutter, quickblox

I have tried the sample code provided by QB but event subscription is not working and the method body is never executed. I am attaching my code for reference

subscribeToEvent() async {

```
try {
  await QB.chat.subscribeMessageEvents( QBChatEvents.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE, (data) {

    print("dbee inside event subscribeMessageEvents");
    Map<String, Object> map = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(data);
    String messageType = map["type"];
    String messageBody = "system message";
    if (messageType == QBChatEvents.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE) {
      Map<String, Object> payload =
      new Map<String, dynamic>.from(map["payload"]);
      messageBody = payload["body"];
      String messageId = payload["id"];
      print("dbee $messageBody $messageId");
    }
  }, );
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print("Error in subscribing");
  print(e);
}
```

I can see the XMPP logs being printed on console when a new message comes but the subscriber is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of QuickBlox Flutter SDK: 0.2.3-alpha .

Next, follow the below steps:

- Settings => init credentials
- Auth => login
- Chat => connect
- Chat => subscribe message events
- Chat => send message

Please note that outgoing messages will also appear in the callback `QBChatEvents.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE`.

Comment: Followed all the steps mentioned and upgraded to 0.2.4-alpha. It's still not working. The subscribeMessageEvents is still not being called. Please help.

Comment: It's now working with the latest release 0.2.5-alpha

Comment: It's not working with 3.3.0-alpha. I have followed all the steps but still not received anything in subscribe function. What I have miss??